# Find minimal path from a to b passing through n intermediary nodes

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization, graph-theory

I have some points in a 100 dimensional space, and wish to find the minimal path that involves `n` intermediary steps to connect point `A` to point `B`. The catch is that one can only get from `A` to `B` by visiting other points in the space (each of which may be visited only once), and one must visit exactly `n` points in the journey from `A` to `B`.

I am currently considering computing the distances between each pair of points, then treating the space as a graph and using Dijkstra's algorithm to find the minimal path from `A` to `B`.

Before implementing this, though, I wanted to ask: Is there an approach to this task that doesn't require the computation of the full pairwise distance matrix?

There are over one million nodes, so the complexity of the Dijkstra approach would be *tremendous*. An approximate solution that doesn't achieve global optimality but minimizes the cost/distance travelled is acceptable. Any suggestions others can offer on this question would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the constraints on the path? The shortest path would obviously be the direct connection between A and B without any intermediate nodes. What exactly does *"one can only get from A to B by visiting other points in the space"* mean?

Comment: Like the constraints on longest step length?

Comment: I can't tell if it is applicable from the info you provide, but you could at least have a quick look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

Comment: Do the intermediate points need to be traversed in a particular order? And can they be traversed more than once? Can we pass through the final goal as an intermediate step before coming back to it in the end? In any case, Dijkstra does not require you to compute the full matrix of pairwise distances in advance, you can compute only distances to neighbors on each step.

Comment: I don't see how Dijkstra helps given your constraint on the number of steps. The problem seems even harder than something Dijkstra could be used on. The exact solution (for anything other than very small `n`) might be infeasible. Are distances in question Euclidean? Also, it is important if the intermediate points can be revisited or need to be distinct. Please clarify.

Comment: To take an extreme case, if `n` is the number of nodes - 2, then the problem is easily seen to be a slight variation of the Traveling Salesman Problem and is thus NP-hard. Even for smaller `n`, your problem strikes me as closer to a TSP problem than a conventional shortest-path problem.

Comment: Thanks for these questions, and for the TSP reference. I hadn't thought of it but that's quite related and gives me some new directions. I updated the question to mention that nodes can't be revisited. @jdhesa the intermediate nodes don't need to be visited in any particular order, but can't be revisited. I'm not sure what it would mean to "pass through" a point; we're just leaping from one observation to the next in the space, and once we reach `B` we're done.

Comment: @duhaime Thanks, sorry I misunderstood your question, I though the `n` points you said were a set of `n` particular vertices you had to go through before reaching the goal, not just the length of the path.